# calabash-android block in start_test_server_in_background

Tags: calabash-android

I've been trying to troubleshoot the issue I am having after I changed my computer with getting .apk file to run properly. I have read all the various solutions, but none worked so far.

I continue to get this error can can't figure out why:
Starting calabash-android console...
Loading /Users/sasaro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.2/irbrc
Running irb...
irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
RuntimeError: App did not start
    from /Users/sasaro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.2/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:609:in `block in start_test_server_in_background'
    from /Users/sasaro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:31:in`perform'
    from /Users/sasaro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/retriable-1.3.3.1/lib/retriable/retriable.rb:59:in `retriable'
    from /Users/sasaro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.2/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:608:in`start_test_server_in_background'
    from /Users/sasaro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.2/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:125:in `start_test_server_in_background'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/sasaro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in`'

What am I doing wrong? What am I not seeing? Is there a solution?

On Mac OS X 10.9.4. The app get's reinstalled when I run reinstall_apps, and when I run start_test_server_in_background I see the app open in the emulator. But, then I get the above error. The app is still usable and running in the emulator.

I'm new at calabash install so please be gentle and detailed if you have come across anything like this.

Comment: is your project resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
calabash-android resign path/to/file.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all Test_Server, delete android app from folder and copy new one after that
Try to:

> calabash-android console app-debug.apk 
>   irb> reinstall_apps
>   irb> start_test_server_in_background
>   it should start

and after that if it wont recognise server try calabash-android resign app-debug.apk
and calbash-android run app-debug.apk

Answer (score 0):

Delete the test_server folder and resign your apk file

```
calabash-android resign path/to/file.apk
```

Then open the console

`calabash-android console path/to/file.apk` 
and

reinstall app by typing

```
reinstall_apps
```

then start your app

```
start_test_server_in_background
```